# CUDA - Sieve of Eratosthenes division into parts

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm writing implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) on GPU. But no sth like this - http://developer-resource.blogspot.com/2008/07/cuda-sieve-of-eratosthenes.html

Method:

1. Creating n-element array with default values 0/1 (0 - prime, 1 - no) and passing it on GPU (I know that it can be done directly in kernel but it's not problem in this moment).
2. Each thread in block checks multiples of a single number. Each block checks in total sqrt(n) possibilities. Each block == different interval.
3. Marking multiples as 1 and passing data back to the host.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define THREADS 1024

__global__ void kernel(int *global, int threads) {
    extern __shared__ int cache[];

    int tid = threadIdx.x + 1;
    int offset = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int number = offset + tid;

    cache[tid - 1] = global[number];
    __syncthreads();

    int start = offset + 1;
    int end = offset + threads;

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if ((i != tid) && (tid != 1) && (i % tid == 0)) {
            cache[i - offset - 1] = 1;
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();
    global[number] = cache[tid - 1];
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *array, *dev_array;
    int n = atol(argv[1]);
    int n_sqrt = floor(sqrt((double)n));

    size_t array_size = n * sizeof(int);
    array = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = 0;
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_array, array_size);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_array, array, array_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int threads = min(n_sqrt, THREADS);
    int blocks = n / threads;
    int shared = threads * sizeof(int);
    kernel<<<blocks, threads, shared>>>(dev_array, threads);
    cudaMemcpy(array, dev_array, array_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("Count: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Run:
./sieve 10240000

It works correctly when n = 16, 64, 1024, 102400... but for n = 10240000 I getting incorrect result. Where is problem?

Comment: Any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code, it's a good idea to use [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589) and also run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.  You **really** should do that **before** posting here.  When I run your code with n=10240000 cuda-memcheck reports an invalid global read of size 4 from the kernel.  If you use that information plus the method described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277365/unspecified-launch-failure-on-memcpy/27278218?s=1|0.3141#27278218) you may be able to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has a variety of problems, in my view.

1. You are fundamentally accessing items out of range.  Consider this sequence in your kernel:

   ```
   int tid = threadIdx.x + 1;
   int offset = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
   int number = offset + tid;

   cache[tid - 1] = global[number];
   ```

   You (in some cases -- see below) have launched a thread array exactly equal in size to your `global` array.  So what happens when the highest numbered thread runs the above code?  `number`  = `threadIdx.x+1+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x`.  This `number` index will be one beyond the end of your array.  This is true for many possible values of `n`.  This problem would have been evident to you if you had either used [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589) or had run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.  You should always do those things when you are having trouble with a CUDA code and also before asking for help from others.
2. The code only has a chance of working correctly if the input `n` is a perfect square.  The reason for this is contained in these lines of code (as well as dependencies in the kernel):

   ```
   int n = atol(argv[1]);
   int n_sqrt = floor(sqrt((double)n));
   ...
   int threads = min(n_sqrt, THREADS);
   int blocks = n / threads;
   ```

   (note that the correct function here would be `atoi` not `atol`, but I digress...) Unless `n` is a perfect square, the resultant `n_sqrt` will be somewhat less than the *actual* square root of `n`.  This will lead you to compute a total thread array that is *smaller* than the necessary size.  (It's OK if you don't believe me at this point.  Run the code I will post below and input a size like 1025, then see if the number of threads * blocks is of sufficient size to cover an array of 1025.)
3. As you've stated:

   > Each block checks in total sqrt(n) possibilities.

   Hopefully this also points out the danger of non-perfect square `n`, but we must now ask "what if `n` is larger than the square of the largest threadblock size (1024)?  The answer is that the code will not work correctly in many cases - and your chosen input of 10240000, although a perfect square, exceeds 1024^2 (1048576) and it does not work for this reason.  Your algorithm (which I claim is **not a Sieve of Eratosthenes**) requires that each block be able to check `sqrt(n)` possibilities, just as you stated in the question.  When that no longer becomes possible because of the limits of threads per block, then your algorithm starts to break.

Here is a code that makes some attempt to fix issue #1 above, and at least give an explanation for the failures associated with #2 and #3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define THREADS 1024
#define MAX 10240000

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


__global__ void kernel(int *global, int threads) {
    extern __shared__ int cache[];

    int tid = threadIdx.x + 1;
    int offset = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int number = offset + tid;

    if ((blockIdx.x != (gridDim.x-1)) || (threadIdx.x != (blockDim.x-1))){
      cache[tid - 1] = global[number];
      __syncthreads();

      int start = offset + 1;
      int end = offset + threads;

      for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if ((i != tid) && (tid != 1) && (i % tid == 0)) {
            cache[i - offset - 1] = 1;
        }
      }
      __syncthreads();
      global[number] = cache[tid - 1];}
}


int cpu_sieve(int n){
    int limit = floor(sqrt(n));
    int *test_arr = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if (test_arr == NULL) return -1;
    memset(test_arr, 0, n*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 2; i < limit; i++)
      if (!test_arr[i]){
        int j = i*i;
        while (j <= n){
          test_arr[j] = 1;
          j += i;}}
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
      if (!test_arr[i]) count++;
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *array, *dev_array;
    if (argc != 2) {printf("must supply n as command line parameter\n"); return 1;}
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if ((n < 1) || (n > MAX)) {printf("n out of range %d\n", n); return 1;}
    int n_sqrt = floor(sqrt((double)n));

    size_t array_size = n * sizeof(int);
    array = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = 0;
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_array, array_size);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_array, array, array_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int threads = min(n_sqrt, THREADS);
    int blocks = n / threads;
    int shared = threads * sizeof(int);
    printf("threads = %d, blocks = %d\n", threads, blocks);
    kernel<<<blocks, threads, shared>>>(dev_array, threads);
    cudaMemcpy(array, dev_array, array_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("some error");
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("Count: %d\n", count);
    printf("CPU Sieve: %d\n", cpu_sieve(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for all comments. I have a question to the first issue. The if statement what you added is needed? I tried avoid accessing items out of range by change `global[number]` to `global[number - 1]`. But after these changes results are incorrect. What is the problem?

Comment: `number-1` will offset all your results by 1.  I wouldn't expect that to "work".  If you run the code I provided as-is with `cuda-memcheck`, it will produce no errors.  If you delete the if statement, and run it with cuda-memcheck, it will indicate errors.  So I would say it is needed.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I changed `global[number - 1]` and `if (array[i - 1] == 0)` in host and it works also.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues, I think, but here's a pointer to the actual problem: The sieve of Eratosthenes removes iteratively multiples of already encountered prime numbers, and you want to separate the work-load into thread-blocks, where each thread-block operates on a piece of shared memory (cache, in your example). Thread-blocks, however, are generally independent from all other thread-blocks and cannot easily communicate with one another. One example to illustrate the problem: The thread with index 0 in thread-block with index 0 removes multiples of 2. Thread blocks with index > 0 have no way to know about this.

Comment: would marking the multiples of odds, instead of primes, help (or 2-3-5... coprimes, i.e. wheel)?

Comment: another way to deal with that might be to work in segments, and use the already known primes to sieve the next block.

Comment: @Peter Klenner, thx but looks on my edited post. I added example what I want to achieve. In my opinion communication between thread-blocks isn't needed. Each thread-blocks works on different interval.

Comment: @Will Ness, I don't mark primes only multiples. When we have n = 64 is sqrt(64) = 8 numbers to check. And I want to each thread-blocks works on different interval and threadIdx == multiple.

Comment: block 1 covers interval 10 - 17 actually. Your loop 

`for (int i = start; i < end; i += tid) {
            cache[i - offset] = 1;
        }` is not suited to detect multiples of primes. For example, number 10 is discounted simply because its the first entry in this thread-block. You would need the modulo operator and extend the loop over the whole segment for each thread. Off the top of my head like this: `for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
if(i%tid==0){
            cache[i - offset] = 1;}
        }`