# CUDA Runtime difference between release mode and debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cuda, nvcc

I am running Visual Studio 2013.
I am running CUDA 7.0.28

I can toggle the runtime difference just by checking or unchecking the CUDA option :

> Generate GPU debug Information.

I have the device kernel running with a <<<1,1>>> and the error occurs even then.

My questions are :

1. Why would it give me different results in the release and debug mode?
2. What kind of things should i be looking for to try and track down why this is occurring.
3. Is there a way to break point within the kernel function?  It does not appear so.  Besides making printf statements what other means can i use to trace down the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Usually running in debug mode results in some *unspecified behaviors* don't terminate the program. For example, I have experienced memory buffers being initialized to zero in the debug mode by default without me explicitly asking to do so. Or some times out-of-range accesses to shared memory buffers causing no termination to the kernel. I suggest catching the error using methods explained in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14038589/2386951). You also should be able to set breakpoints with Nsight for Visual Studio installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would it give me different results in the release and debug mode?

Under the hood, machine code generation from CUDA C/C++ source code will look very different in debug mode. The list of differences is too long to cover here, but mostly they are summarized by *all compiler optimizations are turned off* in debug mode.   This can give rise to race conditions, for example, that are evident in debug but not release or vice versa.

> What kind of things should i be looking for to try and track down why this is occurring.

I would start with the simplest tools.  Use cuda-memcheck first by itself to confirm that the kernel is running without generating basic errors.  If cuda-memcheck reports that your kernel is failing, follow the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277365/unspecified-launch-failure-on-memcpy/27278218#27278218) to isolate the failure to a single line of source code. After fixing any errors reported in this fashion by cuda-memcheck, use the cuda-memcheck [subtool options](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#abstract) including racecheck, synccheck, and initcheck, to see if any of these catch problems.

> Is there a way to break point within the kernel function?

Yes, there are debuggers available both on windows, and linux.  On windows the debugger is integrated into Visual Studio.  There is [documentation available](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition), walkthroughs, and even youtube videos demonstrating how to perform various operations, such as setting a breakpoint.  I wouldn't go down this path before using `cuda-memcheck` however.

Comment: Unfortunately, the memcheck found no errors.  It was unable to run the synccheck or racecheck, maybe because of the <<<1,1>>> declaration.