# Min reduction cuda does not work

Tags: cuda

I wrote a code to find the minimum by reduction. However the result is always zero. I don't know what is the problem. Please help me.

Here it is the kernel code: I modified the sum reduction code from the Nvidia.

```
#include <limits.h>

#define NumThread 128
#define NumBlock 32

__global__ void min_reduce(int* In, int* Out, int n){
  __shared__ int sdata[NumThread];
  unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * NumThread + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int gridSize = NumBlock * NumThread;
  int myMin = INT_MAX;

  while (i < n){
    if(In[i] < myMin)
    myMin = In[i];
    i += gridSize;
  }
  sdata[tid] = myMin;
  __syncthreads();

  if (NumThread >= 1024){
    if (tid < 512)
    if(sdata[tid] > sdata[tid + 512] ) sdata[tid] = sdata[tid + 512];
    __syncthreads();
  }
  if (NumThread >= 512){
    if(sdata[tid] > sdata[tid + 256] ) sdata[tid] = sdata[tid + 256];
    __syncthreads();
  }
  if (NumThread >= 256){
    if(sdata[tid] > sdata[tid + 128] && sdata[tid + 128] !=0) sdata[tid] =  sdata[tid + 128];
    __syncthreads();
  }
  if (NumThread >= 128){
    if(sdata[tid] > sdata[tid + 64] ) sdata[tid] =    sdata[tid + 64];
    __syncthreads();
  }
  //the following practice is deprecated
   if (tid < 32){
    volatile int *smem = sdata;
    if (NumThread >= 64) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 32] ) smem[tid] =  smem[tid+32];
    if (NumThread >= 32) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 16]) smem[tid] =  smem[tid+16];
    if (NumThread >= 16) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 8]) smem[tid] =  smem[tid+8];
    if (NumThread >= 8) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 4] ) smem[tid] =  smem[tid+4];
    if (NumThread >= 4) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 2] ) smem[tid] =  smem[tid+2];
    if (NumThread >= 2) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 1] )      smem[tid] =  smem[tid+1];
  }
  if (tid == 0)
    if(sdata[0] < sdata[1] ) Out[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
    else Out[blockIdx.x] = sdata[1];      
}
```

And here it is my main code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "min_reduction.cu"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  unsigned int length = 1048576;
  int i, Size, min;
  int *a, *out, *gpuA, *gpuOut;

  cudaSetDevice(0);
  Size = length * sizeof(int);
  a = (int*)malloc(Size);
  out = (int*)malloc(NumBlock*sizeof(int));
  for(i=0;i<length;i++) a[i] = (i + 10);

  cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuA,Size);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuOut,NumBlock*sizeof(int));
  cudaMemcpy(gpuA,a,Size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  min_reduce<<<NumBlock,NumThread>>>(gpuA,gpuOut,length);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaMemcpy(out,gpuOut,NumBlock*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  min = out[0];
  for(i=1;i<NumBlock;i++) if(min < out[i]) min = out[i];
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I agree with everything that @HubertApplebaum said, but I can agree with the suggestion to use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).   And as you mention in the code, warp synchronous programming can be considered to be *deprecated* but I cannot support the claim that it is *broken* (yet).  However I don't wish to argue about that; it's not central to your question here.

Another useful debugging suggestion would be to follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277365/unspecified-launch-failure-on-memcpy/27278218#27278218) to compile your code with `-lineinfo` and run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.  If you did that, you would see many reports like this:

```
========= Invalid __shared__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x000001e0 in /home/bob/misc/t1074.cu:39:min_reduce(int*, int*, int)
=========     by thread (64,0,0) in block (24,0,0)
=========     Address 0x00000200 is out of bounds
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2cd) [0x15859d]
=========     Host Frame:./t1074 [0x16dc1]
=========     Host Frame:./t1074 [0x315d3]
=========     Host Frame:./t1074 [0x28f5]
=========     Host Frame:./t1074 [0x2623]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21d65]
=========     Host Frame:./t1074 [0x271d]
```

which would indicate both that a primary problem in your code is that you are incorrectly indexing into your `__shared__`  memory array **as well as the specific line of code where that is taking place**.  Neat!  (It's line 39 in my case, but it would be a different line probably in your case).   If you then drill into that line, you will want to study this section of code:

```
  #define NumThread 128
  ...
  __shared__ int sdata[NumThread];
  ...
  if (NumThread >= 128){
    if(sdata[tid] > sdata[tid + 64] ) sdata[tid] =    sdata[tid + 64]; //line 39 in my case
    __syncthreads();
  }
```

You have defined `NumThread` at 128, and have statically allocated a shared memory array of that many `int` quantities.  All well and good.  What about the code in the if-statement?  That if-condition will be satisfied, which means that all 128 threads in the block will execute the body of that if-statement.  However, you are reading `sdata[tid + 64]` from shared memory, and for threads whose `tid` is greater than 63 (i.e. half of the threads in each block), this will generate an index into shared memory of greater than 127 (which is out-of-bounds, i.e. illegal).

The fix (for this **specific** code that you have shown) is fairly simple, just add another if-test:

```
  if (NumThread >= 128){
    if (tid < 64)
      if(sdata[tid] > sdata[tid + 64] ) sdata[tid] =    sdata[tid + 64];
    __syncthreads();
  }
```

If you make that modification to your code, and rerun the `cuda-memcheck` test, you'll see that all the runtime-reported errors are gone.  Yay!

But the code still doesn't produce the right answer yet.  You've made another error here:

```
  for(i=1;i<NumBlock;i++) if(min < out[i]) min = out[i];
```

If you want to find the *minimum* value, and think about that logic carefully, you'll realize you should have done this:

```
  for(i=1;i<NumBlock;i++) if(min > out[i]) min = out[i];
                                 ^
                                 |
                              greater than
```

With those two changes, your code produces the correct result for me:

```
$ cat t1074.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#include <limits.h>

#define NumThread 128
#define NumBlock 32

__global__ void min_reduce(int* In, int* Out, int n){
  __shared__ int sdata[NumThread];
  unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * NumThread + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int gridSize = NumBlock * NumThread;
  int myMin = INT_MAX;

  while (i < n){
    if(In[i] < myMin)
    myMin = In[i];
    i += gridSize;
  }
  sdata[tid] = myMin;
  __syncthreads();

  if (NumThread >= 1024){
    if (tid < 512)
    if(sdata[tid] > sdata[tid + 512] ) sdata[tid] = sdata[tid + 512];
    __syncthreads();
  }
  if (NumThread >= 512){
    if(sdata[tid] > sdata[tid + 256] ) sdata[tid] = sdata[tid + 256];
    __syncthreads();
  }
  if (NumThread >= 256){
    if(sdata[tid] > sdata[tid + 128] && sdata[tid + 128] !=0) sdata[tid] =  sdata[tid + 128];
    __syncthreads();
  }
  if (NumThread >= 128){
    if (tid < 64)
    if(sdata[tid] > sdata[tid + 64] ) sdata[tid] =    sdata[tid + 64];
    __syncthreads();
  }
  //the following practice is deprecated
   if (tid < 32){
    volatile int *smem = sdata;
    if (NumThread >= 64) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 32] ) smem[tid] =  smem[tid+32];
    if (NumThread >= 32) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 16]) smem[tid] =  smem[tid+16];
    if (NumThread >= 16) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 8]) smem[tid] =  smem[tid+8];
    if (NumThread >= 8) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 4] ) smem[tid] =  smem[tid+4];
    if (NumThread >= 4) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 2] ) smem[tid] =  smem[tid+2];
    if (NumThread >= 2) if(smem[tid] > smem[tid + 1] )      smem[tid] =  smem[tid+1];
  }
  if (tid == 0)
    if(sdata[0] < sdata[1] ) Out[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
    else Out[blockIdx.x] = sdata[1];
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  unsigned int length = 1048576;
  int i, Size, min;
  int *a, *out, *gpuA, *gpuOut;

  cudaSetDevice(0);
  Size = length * sizeof(int);
  a = (int*)malloc(Size);
  out = (int*)malloc(NumBlock*sizeof(int));
  for(i=0;i<length;i++) a[i] = (i + 10);
  a[10]=5;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuA,Size);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&gpuOut,NumBlock*sizeof(int));
  cudaMemcpy(gpuA,a,Size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  min_reduce<<<NumBlock,NumThread>>>(gpuA,gpuOut,length);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaMemcpy(out,gpuOut,NumBlock*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  min = out[0];
  for(i=1;i<NumBlock;i++) if(min > out[i]) min = out[i];
  printf("min = %d\n", min);
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1074 t1074.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1074
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
min = 5
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that you already have the if-check in the 1024 threads case, you may want to add an appropriate if-check to the 512 and 256 threads case, just as I have added it for the 128 threads case above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code works fine, however when I change the input array a , and add this line a[10] = 5; after initialization. The code, can not find the minimum? Can you tell me what is wrong with my code??

Comment: I added a[10]=5; after initialization to the code I posted in my answer and it seems to work fine.  (I've updated the full test case in my answer to show that.)  Perhaps you should ask a new question with your new code that is not working.  Did you add proper cuda error checking and run your code with `cuda-memcheck` ?