# Set the number of blocks and threads in calling a device function in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I have a basic question about calling a device function from a global CUDA kernel. Can we specify the number of blocks and threads when I want to call a device function???

I post an question earlier about min reduction ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353375/min-reduction-cuda-does-not-work)) and I want to call this function inside another global kernel. However the reduction code needs certain blocks and threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two types of functions that can be called on the device:

`__device__` functions are like ordinary `c` or `c++` functions: they operate in the context of a single (CUDA) thread.  It's possible to call these from any number of threads in a block, but from the standpoint of the function itself, it does not automatically create a set of threads like a kernel launch does.

`__global__` functions or "kernels" can *only* be called using a kernel launch method (e.g. `my_kernel<<<...>>>(...);` in the CUDA runtime API).  When calling a `__global__` function via a kernel launch, you specify the number of blocks and threads to launch as part of the kernel configuration (`<<<...>>>`).  If your GPU is of compute capability 3.5 or higher, then you can also call a `__global__` function *from device code* (using essentially the same kernel launch syntax, which allows you to specify blocks and threads for the "child" kernel).  This employs [CUDA Dynamic Parallelism](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism)  which has a whole section of the programming guide dedicated to it.

There are many CUDA sample codes that demonstrate:

1. calling a `__device__` function, such as [simpleTemplates](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-templates)
2. calling a `__global__` function from the device, such as [cdpSimplePrint](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-print--cuda-dynamic-parallelism-)