# CUDA: Cuda memory accessing different than OpenCL? What is causing this illegal memory access?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, gpgpu, memory-access

So I wrote a Cuda version of an OpenCL program I wrote. The OpenCL versions works, meanwhile the Cuda version doesn't. Now converting OpenCL code to Cuda code isn't 1-to-1, but I'm confused as to why the cuda version wouldn't work after all I did base my code around an cuda example when translating it over.

I am getting `an illegal memory access was encountered (error code # = 77)` during a cudaMemcpy(... cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); (line 227) Although it's during a memcpy the problem appears to be an illegal memory access during the kernel run. Here is an example of what I get with cuda-memcheck checking the program:

```
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x000002b8 in MoveoutAndStackCuda(float*, float*, float*, int*, int*, int*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)
=========     by thread (53,0,0) in block (130,0,0)
=========     Address 0x130718e590 is out of bounds
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2c5) [0x204235]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x19a11]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x375b3]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x4059]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x3f0a]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x3f85]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x3438]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x36c9]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x3c46]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x3d4b]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xfd) [0x1ed1d]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x2b69]
=========
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x000002b8 in MoveoutAndStackCuda(float*, float*, float*, int*, int*, int*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)
=========     by thread (52,0,0) in block (130,0,0)
=========     Address 0x130718e590 is out of bounds
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2c5) [0x204235]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x19a11]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x375b3]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x4059]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x3f0a]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x3f85]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x3438]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x36c9]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x3c46]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x3d4b]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xfd) [0x1ed1d]
=========     Host Frame:./MoveoutAndStackCudaMVC [0x2b69]
```

I don't understand the differences between Cuda and OpenCL well enough to know what I am doing wrong. I tried mucking around with `MoveoutAndStackCuda<<<grid, threads>>>` and change it to something like `MoveoutAndStackCuda<<<grid, threads, (localGroupSize * sizeof(float))>>>` but no luck. I've also tried commenting out parts of my kernel the problem appears to occur even when I have commented out most of my kernel.

Hopefully this is verifiable for you, but there is a chance that it isn't since it could depend on my hardware. I am running a [Quadro M5000](http://www.pny.com/nvidia-quadro-m5000) on CentOS 6.8 (Final).

I tried to cut out as much stuff that is useless for this problem as possible. I would also provide the working OpenCL version of this MCV example however I am out of text. I recommend debugging using the arguments 100 50 40  for now, because I also have a problem of spawning too many global threads that I will tackle after this one is solved.

**Here is the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const bool _VERBOSE = true;
const bool _PRINT_ALLOC_SIZE = true;
const bool _PRINT_RUN_TIME = true;
const int MIN_LOCAL_SIZE = 8;

__global__ void MoveoutAndStackCuda(float prestackTraces[], float stackTracesOut[],
  float powerTracesOut[], int startIndices[], int exitIndices[],
  int sampleShift[], const unsigned int samplesPerT, const unsigned int readIns,
  const unsigned int nOuts) {

  unsigned int globalId = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;

  float stackF = 0.0;
  float powerF = 0.0;

  unsigned int readIndex = (globalId % samplesPerT);
  unsigned int jobNum = (globalId / samplesPerT);

  for (unsigned int x = 0; x < readIns; x++) {
    unsigned int offsetIndex = x + (jobNum * readIns);
    unsigned int startInd = startIndices[offsetIndex];

    if ((readIndex >= startInd) && (readIndex < (exitIndices[offsetIndex] + startInd))) {
      float value = prestackTraces[readIndex + (x * samplesPerT) + sampleShift[offsetIndex]];

      stackF += value;
      powerF += (value * value);
    }
  }

  stackTracesOut[globalId] = stackF;
  powerTracesOut[globalId] = powerF;
}

/*
 *  Single threaded version that somewhat mimics what is executed in the OpenCL code as close as possible.
 */
void MoveoutAndStackSingleThread(const float prestackTraces[], float stackTracesOut[],
  float powerTracesOut[], const int startIndices[], const int exitIndices[], const int shift[],
  const unsigned int samplesPerT, const unsigned int readIns, const unsigned int nOuts,
  const unsigned int jobNum, const unsigned int readIndex) {

  float stackF = 0.0f;
  float powerF = 0.0f;

  int outputIndex = readIndex + (jobNum * samplesPerT);

  for (unsigned int x = 0; x < readIns; x++) {
    unsigned int offsetIndex = x + (jobNum * readIns);
    unsigned int startInd = startIndices[offsetIndex];

    bool shouldRead = ((readIndex >= startInd) && (readIndex < (exitIndices[offsetIndex] + startInd)));
    if (shouldRead) {
      float value = prestackTraces[readIndex + (x * samplesPerT) + shift[offsetIndex]];
      stackF += value;
      powerF += (value * value);
    }
  }

  stackTracesOut[outputIndex] = stackF;
  powerTracesOut[outputIndex] = powerF;
}

/**
 *  Used to keep track of how long it takes to execute this.
 */;
double GetTime() {

  struct timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
  return tv.tv_sec + (1e-6 * tv.tv_usec);
}

/*
 *  Print message to stderr and exit.
 */
void Fatal(const char* format, ...) {

  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
  va_end(args);
  exit(1);
}

/*
 *  We have an error, which one? Also print out where this occured.
 */
void CudaWhichError(cudaError_t errorCode, char* location) {

  if (errorCode == cudaSuccess) {
    // This shouldn't happen. It should be made sure that errorCode != cudaSuccess before calling this function.
    printf("Reported error not actually an error... (cudaSuccess) %s\n", location);
    return;
  }

  Fatal("%s %s (error code # = %d)\n", location, cudaGetErrorString(errorCode), errorCode);
}

/*
 *  Check for errors.
 */
void CheckForErrors(char* location) {

  cudaError_t errorCode = cudaGetLastError();
  if (errorCode != cudaSuccess) {
    CudaWhichError(errorCode, location);
  }
}

/*
 *  Finds and initializes the fastest graphics card for CUDA use.
 *
 *  Returns the max number of threads per block for the selected device.
 */
int GetFastestDevice() {

  // Get the number of CUDA devices
  int num;
  if (cudaGetDeviceCount(&num)) Fatal("Cannot get number of CUDA devices\n");
  if (num<1) Fatal("No CUDA devices found\n");

  // Props
  cudaDeviceProp currentDevice;
  int fastestGflops = -1;
  cudaDeviceProp bestDevice;
  int fastestDeviceID = -1;

  //  Get fastest device
  for (int dev=0;dev<num;dev++) {
    if (cudaGetDeviceProperties(&currentDevice, dev)) {
      Fatal("Error getting device %d properties\n", dev);
    }

    int Gflops = currentDevice.multiProcessorCount * currentDevice.clockRate;

    if (_VERBOSE) {
      printf("CUDA Device %d: %s Gflops %f Processors %d Threads/Block %d\n",
        dev,
        currentDevice.name,
        (1e-6 * Gflops),
        currentDevice.multiProcessorCount,
        currentDevice.maxThreadsPerBlock);
    }

    if (Gflops > fastestGflops) {
      fastestGflops = Gflops;
      fastestDeviceID = dev;
      bestDevice = currentDevice;
    }
  }

  // Check to see if we get a device
  if (fastestDeviceID == -1) {
    Fatal("bestDevice == NULL");
  }

  // Print and set device
  if (cudaGetDeviceProperties(&bestDevice, fastestDeviceID)) {
    Fatal("Error getting device %d properties\n", fastestDeviceID);
  }

  cudaSetDevice(fastestDeviceID);

  if (_VERBOSE) {
    printf("Fastest CUDA Device %d: %s\n", fastestDeviceID, bestDevice.name);
    printf("bestDevice.maxThreadsPerBlock: %d\n", bestDevice.maxThreadsPerBlock);
  }

  CheckForErrors((char*)("GetFastestDevice()"));

  // Return max thread count
  return bestDevice.maxThreadsPerBlock;
}

/*
 *  Allocate memory on the GPU, also copy the data over.
 *
 *  CudaPtr variables point to the arrays on the GPU side.
 *  Host variables point to the arrays on the CPU side.
 *  Sizes variables determine sizes of the arrays.
 */
void AllocateAndCopyCudaDeviceMemory(float** prestackCudaPtr, float** stackOutCudaPtr, float** powerOutCudaPtr,
  int** startIndicesCudaPtr, int** endIndicesCudaPtr, int** sampleShiftCudaPtr,
  float *prestackHost, int *startIndicesHost, int *endIndicesHost, int *sampleShiftHost,
  size_t prestackSizes, size_t outputSizes, size_t inputSizes) {

  if (_PRINT_ALLOC_SIZE) {
    size_t totalMemoryAllocated = (prestackSizes + (outputSizes * 2) + (inputSizes * 3));
    printf(" Total memory allocated for run:                        %zu\n", totalMemoryAllocated);
    printf(" Prestack array size:                                   %zu\n", prestackSizes);
    printf(" Output array sizes:                                    %zu\n", outputSizes);
    printf(" EtartIndices, EndIndices, & SampleShift array size:    %zu\n", inputSizes);
  }

  cudaError_t cudaCode;

  // Allocate memory on the graphics card
  cudaCode = cudaMalloc((void**)prestackCudaPtr, prestackSizes);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    ((char*)("cudaErrorMemoryAllocation ERROR: during device memory allocation for prestack array\n")));
  cudaCode = cudaMalloc((void**)stackOutCudaPtr, outputSizes);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    ((char*)("cudaErrorMemoryAllocation ERROR: during device memory allocation for stackOut array\n")));
  cudaCode = cudaMalloc((void**)powerOutCudaPtr, outputSizes);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    ((char*)("cudaErrorMemoryAllocation ERROR: during device memory allocation for powerOut array\n")));
  cudaCode = cudaMalloc((void**)startIndicesCudaPtr, inputSizes);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    ((char*)("cudaErrorMemoryAllocation ERROR: during device memory allocation for startIndices array\n")));
  cudaCode = cudaMalloc((void**)endIndicesCudaPtr, inputSizes);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    ((char*)("cudaErrorMemoryAllocation ERROR: during device memory allocation for endIndices array\n")));
  cudaCode = cudaMalloc((void**)sampleShiftCudaPtr, inputSizes);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    ((char*)("cudaErrorMemoryAllocation ERROR: during device memory allocation for sampleShift array\n")));

  // Copy data over (for the arrays the need it)
  cudaCode = cudaMemcpy(*prestackCudaPtr, prestackHost, prestackSizes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    ((char*)("AllocateAndCopyCudaDeviceMemory ERROR: during copy prestack data over to device.\n")));
  cudaCode = cudaMemcpy(*startIndicesCudaPtr, startIndicesHost, inputSizes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    ((char*)("AllocateAndCopyCudaDeviceMemory ERROR: during copy startIndices data over to device.\n")));
  cudaCode = cudaMemcpy(*endIndicesCudaPtr, endIndicesHost, inputSizes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    ((char*)("AllocateAndCopyCudaDeviceMemory ERROR: during copy endIndices data over to device.\n")));
  cudaCode = cudaMemcpy(*sampleShiftCudaPtr, sampleShiftHost, inputSizes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    ((char*)("AllocateAndCopyCudaDeviceMemory ERROR: during copy sampleSgift data over to device.\n")));
}

/*
 *  Enqueue the kernels to be ran on the gpu. Pointers that are passed in are pointing to
 *  device side memory.
 */
void RunCudaMoveAndStackJobs(float** prestackTracesCudaPtr, float** stackTracesOutCudaPtr,
  float** powerTracesOutCudaPtr, int** startIndicesCudaPtr, int** exitIndicesCudaPtr,
  int** sampleShiftCudaPtr, unsigned int samplesPerT, unsigned int readIns,
  unsigned int nOuts, size_t localGroupSize) {

  // Set the size
  dim3 threads(localGroupSize);
  dim3 grid(samplesPerT * nOuts); 

  if (*prestackTracesCudaPtr == NULL) printf("*prestackTracesCudaPtr == NULL\n");

  // Execute the kernel
  MoveoutAndStackCuda<<<grid, threads>>>(*prestackTracesCudaPtr,
    *stackTracesOutCudaPtr, *powerTracesOutCudaPtr, *startIndicesCudaPtr, *exitIndicesCudaPtr,
    *sampleShiftCudaPtr, samplesPerT, readIns, nOuts);

  CheckForErrors((char*)("RunCudaMoveAndStackJobs()"));
}

/*
 *  Free memory on the GPU device as well as free the remaining OpenCL objects for the host side.
 */
void RetrieveAndCleanupCudaDeviceMemory(float **prestackCudaPtr, float **stackOutCudaPtr,
  float **powerOutCudaPtr, int **startIndicesCudaPtr, int **endIndicesCudaPtr, int **sampleShiftCudaPtr,
  float *stackOutHost, float *powerOutHost, size_t outputSizes) {

  // Copy C from device to host
  cudaError_t cudaCode;
  cudaCode = cudaMemcpy(stackOutHost, *stackOutCudaPtr, outputSizes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    (char*)("RetrieveAndCleanupCudaDeviceMemory ERROR: Cannot copy stackOut data back to host.\n"));
  cudaCode = cudaMemcpy(powerOutHost, *powerOutCudaPtr, outputSizes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  if (cudaCode != cudaSuccess) CudaWhichError(cudaCode,
    (char*)("RetrieveAndCleanupCudaDeviceMemory ERROR: Cannot copy powerOut data back to host.\n"));

  // Free device memory (TODO: reverse order)
  cudaFree(*prestackCudaPtr);
  cudaFree(*stackOutCudaPtr);
  cudaFree(*powerOutCudaPtr);
  cudaFree(*startIndicesCudaPtr);
  cudaFree(*endIndicesCudaPtr);
  cudaFree(*sampleShiftCudaPtr);
}

/*
 * Runs the program given the arrays passed in the parameters.
 *
 * Return the time it took to run the program, if desired.
 */
double CommenceCUDAMoveoutAndStack(float* prestackTraces, float* stackOut, float* powerOut,
  int* startIndices, int* endIndices, int* sampleShift,
  unsigned int samplesPerTrace, unsigned int nTracesIn, unsigned int nTracesOut,
  size_t localGroupSize, size_t prestackSizes, size_t outputSizes, size_t inputSizes) {

  double returnVal = 0.0;
  if (_PRINT_RUN_TIME) {
    printf("CommenceCUDAMoveoutAndStack:\n   samplesPerTrace=%u nTracesIn=%u nTracesOut=%u\n"
      "   localGroupSize=%zu\n",
      samplesPerTrace, nTracesIn, nTracesOut, localGroupSize);
  }

  // Init CUDA
  int maxThreadsPerBlock = GetFastestDevice();

  // Check the desirec local size
  if (((int)localGroupSize) > maxThreadsPerBlock) {
    Fatal("Error: local group (%zu) size exceeds the max local group size of the selected graphics card (%d).\n",
      localGroupSize, maxThreadsPerBlock);
  } else if (((int)localGroupSize) < MIN_LOCAL_SIZE) {
    Fatal("Error: local group (%zu) size is less than MIN_LOCAL_SIZE (%d).\n",
      localGroupSize, MIN_LOCAL_SIZE);
  }

  // Allocate memory on the device. These pointers will point to memory on the GPU.
  double preInitTime = GetTime();
  float* prestackCudaPtr = NULL;
  float* stackOutCudaPtr = NULL;
  float* powerOutCudaPtr = NULL;
  int* startIndicesCudaPtr = NULL;
  int* endIndicesCudaPtr = NULL;
  int* sampleShiftCudaPtr = NULL;
  AllocateAndCopyCudaDeviceMemory(&prestackCudaPtr, &stackOutCudaPtr, &powerOutCudaPtr,
    &startIndicesCudaPtr, &endIndicesCudaPtr, &sampleShiftCudaPtr,
    prestackTraces, startIndices, endIndices, sampleShift,
    prestackSizes, outputSizes, inputSizes);

  // Run the program
  RunCudaMoveAndStackJobs(&prestackCudaPtr, &stackOutCudaPtr, &powerOutCudaPtr,
    &startIndicesCudaPtr, &endIndicesCudaPtr, &sampleShiftCudaPtr,
    samplesPerTrace, nTracesIn, nTracesOut, localGroupSize);

  // Retrieve the data and clean up graphics card memory
  RetrieveAndCleanupCudaDeviceMemory(&prestackCudaPtr, &stackOutCudaPtr, &powerOutCudaPtr,
    &startIndicesCudaPtr, &endIndicesCudaPtr, &sampleShiftCudaPtr,
    stackOut, powerOut,
    (size_t)(nTracesOut * samplesPerTrace * sizeof(float)));

  // Print the run time (if requested)
  if (_PRINT_RUN_TIME) {
    returnVal = (GetTime() - preInitTime);
    if (_PRINT_RUN_TIME) {
      printf("       Run Time:   %f secs\n", returnVal);
    }
  }

  return returnVal;
}

// Returns a float 0.0 - 1.0, inclusive
float RandomFloat() {
  return static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float>(RAND_MAX);
}

// Fill in the prestack traces array
void FillFloatArrayRandomly(float* fillArray, unsigned int length) {

  for (unsigned int r = 0; r < length; r++) {
    fillArray[r] = RandomFloat() * 1000.0f;
  }
}

// Fill the start and end arrays randomly
void FillStartEndShiftArraysRandomly(int* startArray, int* nSampsArray, int* shiftArray,
  int arrayLength, int rangeOfStartEndMax, int samplesPerT) {

  for (int r = 0; r < arrayLength; r++) {
    startArray[r] = (rand() % rangeOfStartEndMax);
    int endIndex = samplesPerT - (rand() % rangeOfStartEndMax);
    nSampsArray[r] = endIndex - startArray[r];

    int range = startArray[r] + (samplesPerT - endIndex);
    int ra = rand();

    if (range != 0) shiftArray[r] = (ra % range) - startArray[r];
    else shiftArray[r] = 0;

    // Check to make sure we won't go out of bounds
    assert((startArray[r] + nSampsArray[r]) <= samplesPerT);
    assert(endIndex > startArray[r]);
    assert(startArray[r] >= 0);
    assert(nSampsArray[r] >= 0);
    assert((startArray[r] + shiftArray[r]) >= 0);
    assert((nSampsArray[r] + shiftArray[r]) <= samplesPerT);
  }
}

// Create arrays for the OpenCL program to use
double GenerateArraysAndRun(unsigned int samplesPerTrace,
  unsigned int nTracesIn, unsigned int nTracesOut, size_t localGroupS) {

  srand(time(NULL)); // Set random seed to current time
  double returnVal;

  // Create the arrays to be used in the program
  float* prestackTraces1D;
  float* stackOut1D;
  float* powerOut1D;
  int* startIndices1D;
  int* endIndices1D;
  int* shift1D;

  // Get sizes or arrays
  size_t prestackSizes = samplesPerTrace * nTracesIn * sizeof(float);
  size_t outputSizes = nTracesOut * samplesPerTrace * sizeof(float);
  size_t inputSizes = nTracesOut * nTracesIn * sizeof(int);

  // Fill in the arrays
  prestackTraces1D = (float*)malloc(prestackSizes);
  stackOut1D = (float*)malloc(outputSizes);
  powerOut1D = (float*)malloc(outputSizes);
  startIndices1D = (int*)malloc(inputSizes);
  endIndices1D = (int*)malloc(inputSizes);
  shift1D = (int*)malloc(inputSizes);

  FillFloatArrayRandomly(prestackTraces1D, samplesPerTrace * nTracesIn);
  FillStartEndShiftArraysRandomly(startIndices1D, endIndices1D, shift1D,
    (int)(nTracesOut * nTracesIn), (int)(((float)samplesPerTrace) * 0.1), (int)samplesPerTrace);

  // Check if arrays were created
  if (prestackTraces1D == NULL) Fatal("GenerateArraysAndRun(): prestackTraces1D == NULL\n");
  if (stackOut1D == NULL) Fatal("GenerateArraysAndRun(): stackOut1D == NULL\n");
  if (powerOut1D == NULL) Fatal("GenerateArraysAndRun(): powerOut1D == NULL\n");
  if (startIndices1D == NULL) Fatal("GenerateArraysAndRun(): startIndices1D == NULL\n");
  if (endIndices1D == NULL) Fatal("GenerateArraysAndRun(): endIndices1D == NULL\n");
  if (shift1D == NULL) Fatal("GenerateArraysAndRun(): shift1D == NULL\n");

  // Run the program
  returnVal = CommenceCUDAMoveoutAndStack(prestackTraces1D, stackOut1D, powerOut1D, startIndices1D,
    endIndices1D, shift1D, samplesPerTrace, nTracesIn, nTracesOut,
    localGroupS, prestackSizes, outputSizes, inputSizes);

  // Finished: free the memory on CPU side in reverse order
  free(shift1D);
  free(endIndices1D);
  free(startIndices1D);
  free(powerOut1D);
  free(stackOut1D);
  free(prestackTraces1D);

  // Return the time that the program gave us
  return returnVal;
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  // TODO: Errors here
  if (argc != 5)
    Fatal("Incorrect # of Arguments (5 Needed) <samplesPerTrace> <nTracesIn> <nTracesOut> <LocalGroupSize>\n"
      "   argc = %d\n", argc);

  unsigned int samplesPerTrace = atoi(argv[1]);
  unsigned int nTracesIn = atoi(argv[2]);
  unsigned int nTracesOut = atoi(argv[3]);

  size_t localGroupS = atoi(argv[4]);

  GenerateArraysAndRun(samplesPerTrace, nTracesIn, nTracesOut, localGroupS);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program requires 4 command line arguments.  You've only suggested 3?  Anyway, you could use the method described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277365/unspecified-launch-failure-on-memcpy/27278218#27278218) to localize the error (out of bounds access) to a particular line of source code in the kernel.  If that is not enough help, you can then use in-kernel `printf` to help identify the issue.

Comment: I believe this line of code in your kernel is triggering the out-of-bounds access: `unsigned int startInd = startIndices[offsetIndex];`  Your computed value for `offsetIndex` is exceeding the allocation size you have created for the `startIndices` array.  You can confirm this by using a `printf` statement before that line to print out illegal values, such as `if (offsetIndex >= 2000) {printf("oops: %d\n", offsetIndex); assert(0);}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was spawning too many blocks. In OpenCL, you tell the kernel the total number of threads and how many threads are in each block, and the total # of blocks is determined from that. Meanwhile in Cuda, you tell the kernel how many blocks there are and how many threads per block there is, and the total # of threads is determined by those. So:

```
  dim3 threads(localGroupSize);
  dim3 grid(samplesPerT * nOuts);
```

Should be:

```
  dim3 threads(localGroupSize);
  dim3 grid((samplesPerT * nOuts) / localGroupSize);
```