# Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (77 vs. 0) an illegal memory access was encountered

Tags: cuda

I'm debugging some lengthy code which involves some cuda operations.
I' currently getting the above mentioned error during a call to `cudaMemcpy(...,...,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)` but I'm not sure it is speficially related to that.

Here is a code snippet:

```
    int num_elements = 8294400; // --> I also tried it with "1" here which didn't work either!
    float *checkArray = new float[num_elements];
    float *checkArray_GPU;
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&checkArray_GPU, num_elements * sizeof(float)));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(checkArray_GPU, checkArray, num_elements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CUDA_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(checkArray, checkArray_GPU, num_elements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

where CUDA_CHECK is simply a macro for printing any cuda error (this was part of the existing code and works fine for all other cudaMemcpy oder cudaMalloc calls so it is not part of the problem). Strangely this code snippet executed separately in a toy `*.cu` example works fine.

So my assumption is that due to previous cuda operations in the program, there have been some errors which have not been reported that cause the bug in the code snippet above. Could that be?
Is there a way to check if there is some unreported error involving cuda?

My other estimate is that it might come from the specific graphic card I'm using. I have a Nvidia Titan X Pascal, Cuda 8.0 and cudnn v5.1. I also tried to compile my code using [some special compiler flags](http://arnon.dk/matching-sm-architectures-arch-and-gencode-for-various-nvidia-cards/) like

```
-arch=sm_30 \
 -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
 -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
 -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
 -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
 -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 \
 -gencode=arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
 -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
 -gencode=arch=compute_62,code=sm_62 \
```

but it didn't help so far. Here is my current simplified Makefile for completeness:

```
NVCC = nvcc
CUDA_INC = -I/usr/local/cuda/include 
CUDA_LIB = -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
TARGET = myProgramm
OPTS = -std=c++11
$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    $(NVCC) $(OPTS) -shared $(TARGET).o $(CUDA_LIB) -o $(TARGET).so
$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cu headers/some_header.hpp 
    $(NVCC) $(OPTS) $(CUDA_INC) -Xcompiler -fPIC -c $(TARGET).cu
```

Has anyone an idea how I could get to the bottom of this?

**Edit**:
cuda-memcheck was a good idea, so the error apparantly happens earlier during a call of `Kernel_set_value`:

```
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 4
=========     at 0x00000298 in void Kernel_set_value<float>(unsigned long, unsigned long, float*, float)
=========     by thread (480,0,0) in block (30,0,0)
=========     Address 0x0005cd00 is out of bounds
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2c5) [0x209035]
[...]
=========     Host Frame:/media/.../myProgramm.so (_ZN5boost6python6detail6invokeIiPFvRKSsENS0_15arg_from_pythonIS4_EEEEP7_objectNS1_11invoke_tag_ILb1ELb0EEERKT_RT0_RT1_ + 0x2d) [0x3e5eb]
[...]
=========
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 4) due to "unspecified launch failure" on CUDA API call to cudaMemcpy. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 [0x2f4e33]
=========     Host Frame:/media/.../myProgramm.so [0x7489f]
F0703 16:23:54.840698 26207 myProgramm.cu:411] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (4 vs. 0)  unspecified launch failure
[...]
=========     Host Frame:python (Py_Main + 0xb5e) [0x66d92]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21f45]
=========     Host Frame:python [0x177c2e]
=========
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
========= Error: process didn't terminate successfully
========= Internal error (20)
========= No CUDA-MEMCHECK results found
```

but also the function `Kernel_set_value` works fine in a toy example. Is there anything special to consider when using `Kernel_set_value`. This is it's source code and it's respective helper functions.

```
#define CUDA_NUM_THREADS 512
#define MAX_NUM_BLOCKS 2880

inline int CUDA_GET_BLOCKS(const size_t N) {
  return min(MAX_NUM_BLOCKS, int((N + size_t(CUDA_NUM_THREADS) - 1) / CUDA_NUM_THREADS));
}

inline size_t CUDA_GET_LOOPS(const size_t N) {
  size_t total_threads = CUDA_GET_BLOCKS(N)*CUDA_NUM_THREADS;
  return (N + total_threads -1)/ total_threads;
}

template <typename Dtype>
__global__ void Kernel_set_value(size_t CUDA_NUM_LOOPS, size_t N, Dtype* GPUdst, Dtype value){
  const size_t idxBase = size_t(CUDA_NUM_LOOPS) * (size_t(CUDA_NUM_THREADS) * size_t(blockIdx.x) + size_t(threadIdx.x));
  if (idxBase >= N) return;
  for (size_t idx = idxBase; idx < min(N,idxBase+CUDA_NUM_LOOPS); ++idx ){
    GPUdst[idx] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: is `num_crop_voxels` equal to `num_elements`?

Comment: yes, i will edit that

Comment: run your code with cudamemcheck.

Comment: "Is there anything special to consider when using `Kernel_set_value`?"  I don't see how anyone could answer that without knowing what `Kernel_set_value` is or what the code for it looks like, or what code you are working on.  When you ask for debugging help on SO you are supposed to provide a  [mcve].  Also, with `cuda-memcheck`, you can follow the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277365/unspecified-launch-failure-on-memcpy/27278218#27278218) to have `cuda-memcheck` identify the specific line of kernel code that the error happened on.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought Kernel_set_value was a elementary cuda-function.  Thanks to your hint of compiling with the `-lineinfo` option I could localize the respective function. Since the error message is `Address ... is out of bounds` I will go over the code again checking all array dimensions... Already getting this error brings me much further than I was before. I could now localize the error much better than with the original error message (`error == cudaSuccess (77 vs. 0)`).

Answer (score -1):

So the final solution was to compile the code without any `-gencode=arch=compute_XX,code=sm_XX`-style flags. Took me forever to find this out. The actual error codes were very missleading (`error == cudaSuccess (77 vs. 0) an illegal memory access`, `(4 vs. 0) unspecified launch failure` or `(8 vs. 0) invalid device function`

Comment: You've never mentioned `invalid device function` until this answer.  That error code is almost always indicative of compiling for the wrong architecture (and removing all architecture switches will default to `sm_20` compilation, which is the most unrestrictive).  However the other error codes you mention (`illegal memory access` and `unspecified launch failure`) are associated with other issues.  Lumping them all together and suggesting they are all due to compile arch switch selection is simply incorrect.