# Debugging CUDA MMU Fault

Tags: c++, cuda

In my code I repeatedly get memory access errors, and I cannot find the reason why this would happen.

What is a MMU error on CUDA in the first place, and how can I debug where its coming from? Currently it happens when defining a lambda function, but when I rewrite the code it happens at some other place, so its quite undefined behaviour, and I don't know how to even start debugging this.

Answer (score 2):

The MMU fault you are referring to is presumably an Xid 31 error as described [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/index.html#topic_5_2).

The most common reason for this in my experience is a CUDA code defect (code written by CUDA user, i.e. GPU kernel/device code) that results in an error occurring during the execution of a GPU kernel.  Such issues, in my experience, are nearly always capturable/localizable using `cuda-memcheck`.  (You can also use a debugger as described in the link above).

For these cases, the best method to begin the debug, IMO, is to start using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277365/unspecified-launch-failure-on-memcpy/27278218#27278218).  It is essentially what is being referred to in the document I linked above.  Using that method, `cuda-memcheck` is generally able to localize the error to a specific line of source code for you.  Thereafter you have additional debug avenues you can pursue, using in-kernel `printf` and/or a debugger, as described.

If `cuda-memcheck` does not report any issues, but the Xid 31 error is logged in your system logs each time you run a particular app, then as indicated in the first linked document, this is not really end-user debuggable (and should be a rare occurrence) and the only recourse at that point is to file a bug at developer.nvidia.com, using the general method described [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-report-a-bug/67911).

Comment: This question is about someone's own code. If it was about running a particular app, it would be off-topic on this website.