# CUDA syncthreads() block other threads

Tags: cuda

```
#define TS 32
int num_devices = 0;

__global__ void shared_kernel(float* A, float* B, float* C, int M, int N, int K) {

   int global_col = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
   int global_row = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
   int local_col  = threadIdx.x;
   int local_row  = threadIdx.y;
   if (global_row >= M || global_col >= N) return;


   __shared__ float Asub[TS][TS];
   __shared__ float Bsub[TS][TS];
 
   const int num_tiles = K / TS;

   float acc = 0;
 
   for(int t = 0; t < num_tiles; t++){
       const int t_row = TS * t + local_row;
       const int t_col = TS * t + local_col;
       Asub[local_row][local_col] = A[global_row * K + t_col];
       Bsub[local_row][local_col] = B[t_row * N + global_col];


       __syncthreads();
       printf("[DEBUG] first sync threads, global_row: %d, global_col: %d\n", global_row, global_col);
 

       for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
         acc += Asub[local_row][k] * Bsub[k][local_col];
       }
 

       __syncthreads();
       printf("[DEBUG] second sync threads, global_row: %d, global_col: %d\n", global_row, global_col);
   }

   C[global_row * N + global_col] = acc;
}

static float *a_d, *b_d, *c_d;

void mat_mul(float *A, float *B, float *C, int M, int N, int K) {
 cudaMemcpy(a_d, A, M * K * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMemcpy(b_d, B, K * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

 dim3 blockDim(TS, TS);
 dim3 gridDim(M/TS, N/TS);
 shared_kernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(a_d, b_d, c_d, M, N, K); 

 cudaMemcpy(C, c_d, M * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

void mat_mul_init(float *A, float *B, float *C, int M, int N, int K) {

 cudaGetDeviceCount(&num_devices); 
 cudaSetDevice(0);

 cudaMalloc(&a_d, M * K * sizeof(float));
 cudaMalloc(&b_d, K * N * sizeof(float));
 cudaMalloc(&c_d, M * N * sizeof(float));
}
```

Above example is a matrix multiplication with shared memory.
I ran above kernel with `dim3 blockDim(TS, TS)` and `dim3 gridDim(M/TS, N/TS)` and M, N, K = 128.

I checked that `float * C` has zero value after launching kernel. Also, I found that only few of global_row are printed(from 37 to 81) after first `__syncthreads()`, and there is no `printf` DEBUG message after the second `__syncthreads()`.

I suspect that `__syncthreads()` is causing the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. My code is almost the same as other matrix multiplication code in other site.

Would you give me some hint how to solve this?

Comment: Could you at least post the complete kernel, better still an [MCVE]. You are asking for someone to diagnose a runtime error on code that can't be compiled, let alone run. Does that sound like a reasonable proposition to you?

Comment: I'm sorry I uploaded a full kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code, I recommend using [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) and run your code with `compute-sanitizer` or `cuda-memcheck`.  For this type of analysis, it will be easier if you *don't* use in-kernel `printf`.

If you did that, you would see output like this:

```
========= Invalid __shared__ read of size 4
=========     at 0x000002f0 in shared_kernel(float*, float*, float*, int, int, int)
=========     by thread (0,2,0) in block (0,1,0)
=========     Address 0x00002000 is out of bounds
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
...  (and more output)
```

So from that, we can see that your kernel is making invalid `__shared__` read operations.  Where is that happening in your kernel?  You could use the methodology [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277365/unspecified-launch-failure-on-memcpy/27278218#27278218) to identify a specific line of code.  However this is a fairly simple kernel, and there is only one line that is reading from shared memory, it is here:

```
   for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
     acc += Asub[local_row][k] * Bsub[k][local_col];  // shared reads here
```

A quick inspection will show that if you let this loop iterate over a range of `K=128`, then you will index out of bounds here:

```
   for (int k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
     acc += Asub[local_row][k] * Bsub[k][local_col];
                            ^         ^
```

when `k` is greater than 31, because this would exceed your shared array dimensions:

```
#define TS 32

__shared__ float Asub[TS][TS];
__shared__ float Bsub[TS][TS];
```

I'm not going to bother writing a fixed kernel/code for you, because as you've already pointed out, this topic is covered in many other places, and a canonical example is already provided in [the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory).

FWIW, if i change your for-loop to this:

```
   for (int k = 0; k < TS; ++k) {
```

then the run-time errors go away for me.  `cuda-memcheck` reports no errors.