# How to make my Cuda kernel run on bigger matrixes?

Tags: c++, matrix, parallel-processing, cuda

So my code is suppsed to work like this:

-take in_martix of NxN elements and R factor

-it should give back a matrix of size [N-2R]*[N-2R] with each element being a sum of in_matrix elements in R radius [it should work like this for N=4 R=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etBVl.png)
Even though my code works for smaller matrixes, for bigger ones like 1024 or 2048 or even bigger R factors it gives back a matrix of 0's. Is it a problem inside my code or just my GPU can't compute more calculations ?
Code: (for testing purposes initial matrix is filled with 1's so every element of out_matrix  should == (2R+1)^2

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_profiler_api.h>
#define N 1024
#define R 128
#define K 1
#define THREAD_BLOCK_SIZE 8
using namespace std;

__global__ void MatrixStencil(int* d_tab_begin, int* d_out_begin, int d_N, int d_R, int d_K) {
    int tx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int ty = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int out_local = 0;

    for (int col = tx; col <= tx + 2 * d_R ; col++)
        for (int row = ty; row <= ty + 2 * d_R ; row++)
            out_local += *(d_tab_begin + col * d_N + row);

    *(d_out_begin + (tx) * (d_N - 2 * R) + ty) = out_local;

}
void random_ints(int tab[N][N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            tab[i][j] = 1;
}

int main() {

    static int tab[N][N];
    random_ints(tab);

    int tab_size = sizeof(int) * N * N;
    int out_size = sizeof(int) * (N - 2 * R) * (N - 2 * R);

    dim3 BLOCK_SIZE(THREAD_BLOCK_SIZE, THREAD_BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 GRID_SIZE(ceil((float)N / (float)(THREAD_BLOCK_SIZE  )), ceil((float)N / (float)(THREAD_BLOCK_SIZE  )));

    void** d_tab;
    void** d_out;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_tab, tab_size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out, out_size);

    cudaMemcpyAsync(d_tab, tab, tab_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int* d_tab_begin = (int*)(d_tab);
    int* d_out_begin = (int*)(d_out);

    MatrixStencil << < GRID_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE>> > (d_tab_begin, d_out_begin, N, R, K);

    int* out = (int*)malloc(out_size);
    
    cudaMemcpyAsync(out, d_out, out_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    for (int col = 0; col < N - 2 * R; col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < N - 2 * R; row++)
        {
            cout << *(out + ((col * (N - 2 * R)) + row)) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. replace the deprecated `cudaThreadSynchronize()` with `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`. 2. use [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  3. run your code with `compute-sanitizer` and study the errors.  You may wish to follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277365/unspecified-launch-failure-on-memcpy/27278218#27278218) also.  Your code, as posted, is making illegal memory accesses from kernel/device code (invalid global writes of size 4 bytes) in `MatrixStencil`.

Comment: The allocated size of `d_out_begin` is `(N-2*R)^2` elements.  In your kernel code, both `tx` and `ty` can take on values from 0..N-1.  Let's put them both at `N-1`. With those values of `tx` and `ty`, does the output pointer indexing: `(tx) * (d_N - 2 * R) + ty` produce an index/offset that is within the allocated range?  (hint: it does not).  The allocated size for your chosen values of N,R is 589824 elements.  The in-kernel index calculation for those values of `tx` and `ty` is 786687 which is clearly out of range.

Answer (score 1):

Finally thanks to Robert I found how to make the code work - by adding if statment

```
if ((tx < d_N - 2 * d_R) && (ty < d_N - 2 * d_R)) {
        for (int col = tx; col <= tx + 2 * d_R; col++)
            for (int row = ty; row <= ty + 2 * d_R; row++)
                out_local += *(d_tab_begin + col * d_N + row);

        *(d_out_begin + (tx) * (d_N - 2 * R) + ty) = out_local;
    }
```

Comment: Leave more information why did you change the code like that in the answer, so that others can actually understand why that's the case and how you got to the answer.